# Como trabalhar o retorno de uma query select max?

Tags: php, html, sql, select, back-end

Serei breve:

Ao tentar trabalhar os valores de uma query que utiliza o MAX, recebo o erro:
Use of undefined constant protocolo - assumed 'nome do campo'.

Tabela:
[image: Tabela atestados]

Select:

```
$atestados = $conect -> query( "select max(protocolo) from atestados");
```

Php trabalhando o retorno no HTML:

```
while ( $temp = $atestados->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo $temp[protocolo];
}
```

tambem tentei assim:

```
while ( $temp = $atestados->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo $temp[max(protocolo)];
}
```

Erro:
[image: erro]

Ps. valores randomicos para teste

Comment: Está usando o PDO ou mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

dê um alias para o max:

```
$atestados = $conect -> query( "select max(protocolo) AS protocolo from atestados");
```

e utilize o php dessa maneira:

```
while ( $temp = $atestados->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo $temp['protocolo'];
}
```

Comment: Não adiantou...

Comment: Qual erro agora?

Answer (score 0):

tente utilizando o fetch() no for

```
$atestados = $conect -> query( "select max(protocolo) AS maximo from atestados");
foreach( $temp = $atestados->fetch() ) {
    echo $temp["maximo"];

}
```

caso não obitenha resultados, use o  na sua conexão PDO

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', $opcoes);
```

e poste mais detalhes aqui